Dask distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to deserialize with OutOfData exception
I want to use XGBoost with Dask, which requires a client to be passed to the train method. When I try to read the data without defining a client, everything works fine, but when I run the code below I get distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to deserialize with an OutOfData exception.
from distributed import Client
import dask.dataframe as dd

client = Client()
dda = dd.read_parquet(fr"C:\Users\marij\Documents\GitHub\Research_Project\Data\small.parquet", engine="pyarrow").to_dask_array(lengths=True)

The full error traceback:
2024-12-22 14:27:30,821 - distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to deserialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 128, in unpackb
    ret = unpacker._unpack()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 565, in _unpack
    ret.append(self._unpack(EX_CONSTRUCT))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 592, in _unpack
    ret[key] = self._unpack(EX_CONSTRUCT)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 565, in _unpack
    ret.append(self._unpack(EX_CONSTRUCT))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 546, in _unpack
    typ, n, obj = self._read_header()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 488, in _read_header
    obj = self._read(n)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 405, in _read
    self._reserve(n, raise_outofdata=raise_outofdata)
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 420, in _reserve
    raise OutOfData
msgpack.exceptions.OutOfData

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 175, in loads
    return msgpack.loads(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 130, in unpackb
    raise ValueError("Unpack failed: incomplete input")
ValueError: Unpack failed: incomplete input
2024-12-22 14:27:30,832 - distributed.core - ERROR - Exception while handling op register-client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 128, in unpackb
    ret = unpacker._unpack()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 565, in _unpack
    ret.append(self._unpack(EX_CONSTRUCT))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 592, in _unpack
    ret[key] = self._unpack(EX_CONSTRUCT)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 565, in _unpack
    ret.append(self._unpack(EX_CONSTRUCT))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 546, in _unpack
    typ, n, obj = self._read_header()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 488, in _read_header
    obj = self._read(n)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 405, in _read
    self._reserve(n, raise_outofdata=raise_outofdata)
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 420, in _reserve
    raise OutOfData
msgpack.exceptions.OutOfData

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\distributed\core.py", line 831, in _handle_comm
    result = await result
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\distributed\scheduler.py", line 5902, in add_client
    await self.handle_stream(comm=comm, extra={"client": client})
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\distributed\core.py", line 886, in handle_stream
    msgs = await comm.read()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\tcp.py", line 247, in read
    msg = await from_frames(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\utils.py", line 78, in from_frames
    res = _from_frames()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\utils.py", line 61, in _from_frames
    return protocol.loads(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 175, in loads
    return msgpack.loads(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 130, in unpackb
    raise ValueError("Unpack failed: incomplete input")
ValueError: Unpack failed: incomplete input
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-321' coro=<Server._handle_comm() done, defined at c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\distributed\core.py:737> exception=ValueError('Unpack failed: incomplete input')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 128, in unpackb
    ret = unpacker._unpack()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 565, in _unpack
    ret.append(self._unpack(EX_CONSTRUCT))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 592, in _unpack
    ret[key] = self._unpack(EX_CONSTRUCT)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 565, in _unpack
    ret.append(self._unpack(EX_CONSTRUCT))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 546, in _unpack
    typ, n, obj = self._read_header()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 488, in _read_header
    obj = self._read(n)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 405, in _read
    self._reserve(n, raise_outofdata=raise_outofdata)
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 420, in _reserve
    raise OutOfData
msgpack.exceptions.OutOfData

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\distributed\core.py", line 831, in _handle_comm
    result = await result
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\distributed\scheduler.py", line 5902, in add_client
    await self.handle_stream(comm=comm, extra={"client": client})
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\distributed\core.py", line 886, in handle_stream
    msgs = await comm.read()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\tcp.py", line 247, in read
    msg = await from_frames(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\utils.py", line 78, in from_frames
    res = _from_frames()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\utils.py", line 61, in _from_frames
    return protocol.loads(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 175, in loads
    return msgpack.loads(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\marij\miniconda3\envs\research_project_dask\Lib\site-packages\msgpack\fallback.py", line 130, in unpackb
    raise ValueError("Unpack failed: incomplete input")
ValueError: Unpack failed: incomplete input

Some package versions (let me know if more is required):
dask                      2024.8.2
dask-core                 2024.8.2
dask-expr                 1.1.13
dask-glm                  0.3.2
dask-ml                   2024.4.4
dask-xgboost              0.1.11
distributed               2024.8.2
pyarrow                   18.1.0
pyarrow-core              18.1.0

What might be the reason for this?

So just read_parquet call is failing? Could you try a simple Future computation to see if your distributed local cluster is functionnal?
